# Pass uploaded excel file data to python via ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I currently have a choose file option in which a user can upload an excel file. Following is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    Upload excel
    <input type="file" id="file_upload" class="file_upload">
    <button type="button" id="upload_submit" class="btn btn-primary upload_submit">Upload</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("body").on("click", ".upload_submit", function () {
    // debugger
    var filepath = $("#file_upload").val()
})
```

I am trying to extract the file-path and send the path to python so that i can do my operations in the back end. but I am getting the path as **'C:\fakepath\dummy_data.xls'**

After some googling, I came to know that latest browsers restrict revealing the users directory from the client side.

So, Pls suggest, how do i send this excel data to my python function in the back end?

Comment: You have entire file, then what you want to do with path ?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede, How do i get the file in js and pass the same to python? can u please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal example for uploading file,

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        f = FileUpload()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        import ipdb;
        ipdb.set_trace()
        f = FileUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if f.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = f.cleaned_data['file_object']
            # manipulate file here.

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': f})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('upload/', views.upload, name='uoload'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );

    $("#upload-btn").click(function (event) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "/upload/",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#result").text(data);
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            },
            error: function (e) {

                $("#result").text(e.responseText);
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            }
        });

    });
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="/upload/" method="post" id="file-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='upload-btn'>Upload</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant!... Will try and let you know